# What do these curly graphics represent on this map?

Tags: cartography, geology, new-zealand, historical-maps

What do the two curly graphics to the left and right of this map represent? They are the only two on the map and seem to be attached to the border of an area.

[image]

I'm sorry I haven't posted the full map, I'm not sure I'm allowed.

Comment: Do you mean the things that sort of look like a `J` ? You'll have to give more information about the map. who made it? when was it published? Things like that.

Comment: Yes, @DevdattaTengshe. Originally published around 1900 in New Zealand.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The curly S shaped symbol, called an "area brace symbol" was used to indicate that the two properties actually share the same property number.  It's possible that it was all once considered one property but the middle bit was subdivided and the two properties on the side maintain the same number.

The symbol is also called a "field tie" and sometimes called a "Vinculum".  Though, I don't know how common the latter is.

**[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol))** states that Vinculum, which is also used in mathematics, is Latin for "bond", "fetter", "chain", or "tie", which is suggestive of some of the uses of the symbol.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense as the two areas have the same outline style too. I think in this case a lot of smaller properties around the central one were merged but are not physically connected.

Comment: Another term for them is "land hooks".

Comment: Nice. I had no idea.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some more information about vinculums (vinvulae?) as I recently encountered some of these, too. Land Information New Zealand has a FAQ which has the following section:

> **Why are some parcels not contiguous (ie they are separated by other parcels)?**
>
> Multi-polygons exist primarily for parcels that have a single survey appellation but may be physically divided. They are therefore in the same title (where a title exists). A common example is where a road cuts through a parcel, but two individual parcels were not created on the survey. On old survey plans, these would be shown with the parcels linked together with a **vinculum** (a symbol like a broken ‘s’). Under the Rules for Cadastral Survey 2010, surveyors are no longer allowed to create new multi-polygon parcels.

Judging by your map snippet, perhaps the mine divided a parcel of land, which was not subsequently redivided into two sections.

Source: http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/linz-data-service/linz-data-service-faqs

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms, it means the ownership on either side is the same entity.